# Keep object assigned in the same position when changing animations

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, nla-editor

I am using animations from Mixamo for my character, but upon making the weapon the child of the hand bone, some animations work fine and others change the position drastically, is there an easy fix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, you are new here...but...we do this in our free time and we cannot mind reading (yet). So please give us as many details as possible like e.g. which animations work and which don't? You show us nearly no settings - how shall we know what you did? since you seem to be a beginner maybe the best way to help us that we can help you would be if you provide your blend file.

Comment: Hello! 
Thank you for the feedback, the animation that works is the one shown in the top image, where the weapon is nicely alignged, and the one that isnt is the bottom one. I use the action editor to manage and change between animations in the view port.

What would be the best way to share a blend file?

Comment: File-sharing on BSE is via https://blend-exchange.com/ ... follow the instructions there.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=nvy91K4G" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/nvy91K4G/)
This is the file!